# ImageView OnTouchListener delay

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So, basically I have a clickable ImageView with a listener:

```
 imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                //do something while pressed
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                //when finger is lifted
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

It works, but the problem is that there is an annoying delay between the moment when I press the ImageView and when the code is actually executed. 
Is there any way to fix it? I've read about a prepressed state that may fix it, can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: what delay? how did you measure it?

Comment: A lag. I didn't measure it, but it's like 0.5 sec from the moment I press on the image and the moment the code is executed.

Comment: does it happen with ordinary View too or only with ImageView?

Comment: I tried the same code with a normal Button and ImageButton but it still happens.

Comment: so your device is either extremely cheap or extremely busy,  if the latter try to stop suspicious apps/boot the device

Comment: @pskink But I'm developing on a Samsung S5! Anyway, looks like now is solved. As soon as I unplugged the device from the PC the app began to work properly.